# Link library against Python 2 and Python 3 library

Tags: python, c, gcc, hyperlink

I want to create a library which is linked against `libpython2.so` and `libpython3.so` to be able to execute Python2 and Python 3 scripts. The problem is that both libraries contain function with the same name. I tried to solve the problem the following way:

- support module `foo-python2.c` for Python 2 support, which is linked against `libpython2.so`
- support module `foo-python3.c` for Python 3 support, which is linked against `libpython3.so`
- main file `foo-main.c` which calls init functions in the Python 2 and Python 3 support modules and is linked with `foo-python2.o` and `foo-python3.o`.

When libfoo.so is loaded Python 2 initialization is working as expected, but when I try to access Python 3 function it does not work as expected.
In the Python 3 support library when I call `Py_IsInitialized()` is returns true, although the `libpython3.so` was not loaded with `g_module_open`. So my assumption is that `Py_IsInitialized` points to the Python 2 version. When I ignore this and call `g_module_open("/usr/lib/libpython3.so", 0)` and call some `Py_*` functions the module crashes.

How do I correctly link the 3 objects to solve my problem?

Comment: 1) Python is a programing language, not a scripting language. 2) I strongly doubt this makes any sense.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Why be rude? He is talking about linking to shared objects one used pyhton2 and the other using python3 which appears to be calling the python3 init instead.

Comment: op did you ever find a way to do this? I wonder if once you start either Py_Initialized() for python2 or python3 it just sticks that that one. I think the links for the python interpreter get mangled or confused.